# jq filter json by dates

Tags: json, jq

I have some json that looks like this

```
 {
  "users":[ {  
     "id":8734,
     "last_login":"2016-10-04T06:59:40Z"
  },
  {  
    "id":9376,
    "last_login":"2016-05-04T20:37:32Z"
  },
  {  
    "id":9376,
    "last_login":null
  }
]}
```

I want to return ids that the last login date is > 90days so in this case it should only return 9376.  I am thinking I need to use fromdateiso8601  in combination with a select but am having a little trouble getting the syntax right.

This seems to work

```
.users[] | select ( .last_login | fromdateiso8601 > 1475625600) | .id
```

but I still get

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): strptime/1 requires string inputs and arguments
```

how do I deal with the null,  ideally those would be included in the results.

Answer (score 8):

Just add the appropriate null checks.

```
.users[] | select (.last_login | . == null or fromdateiso8601 > 1475625600).id
```

Comment: Jeff - Shouldn't that be `and` ?

Comment: Actually I meant it to be an `or`, but I had the first condition wrong. He mentioned we wanted to include the results with `null` values.

Answer (score 7):

One way to protect against null values of .last_login would be as follows:

```
.users[]
| select ( .last_login // empty | fromdateiso8601 > 1475625600)
| .id
```

For clarity, though, I'd add parentheses, e.g.:

```
.users[]
| select ( (.last_login // empty) | fromdateiso8601 > 1475625600)
| .id
```

Or more defensively still, use `?`:

```
.users[]
| select ( .last_login | fromdateiso8601? > 1475625600)
| .id
```

If you want to include items for which .last_login evaluates to `null`, then you could use the filter that Jeff suggested, or perhaps:

```
 (.last_login | fromdateiso8601? > 1475625600) // true
```

P.S. For "90 days before now, expressed in seconds since the beginning of the Unix epoch", you could use:

```
def daysAgo(days):  (now | floor) - (days * 86400);
```