# GET Request by CURL is ignoring params

Tags: bash, shell, api, curl, command-line

I'm trying to call GET request with params.
The problem is that the response is ignoring from the params.

This is the curl:

```
curl -X GET https://api.helpscout.net/v2/customers \
     -H 'Accept: application/json' \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer xxx" \
     -d 'query=(createdAt:[2019-06-01T00:00:00Z TO 2019-07-01T00:00:00Z])&status=all&page=1'
```

The result that I'm getting from this call bring me "createdAt" =2019-07-22 instead of createdAt between 2019-06-01 - 2019-07-01.

How can I call GET request and combining the params?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing parameters from different endpoints. The endpoint in your question is the 'customers' endpoint, however, you are using parameters from the 'conversation' endpoint.

According to the documentation (https://developer.helpscout.com/mailbox-api/endpoints/customers/list/), `createdAt` is an option for `sortField`, not `query`. This only allows you to use `createdAt` to sort responses in ascending or descending order.

There does not appear to be an option to return customers based on the `createdAt` field. Also, 'customers' do not have a `status`, while 'conversations' do have a `status`.

A query using the 'customers' endpoint and the parameter `createdAt` would look like this:

```
sortField=createdAt&sortOrder=desc
```

This would sort the responses in descending order, but would not filter them by date.

A shell solution would be to return all results, then use a library like `jq` to filter your JSON response by date. This posting describes how to filter by dates with `jq`: [jq filter json by dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881728/jq-filter-json-by-dates)