# How to get git events of repo for specific time period with CURL?

Tags: git, curl, github, github-api

i need to get the git events for specific time period with CURL
When i try:-

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo/events
```

it shows all the events

how can i get after=2019-11-01T00:00:00Z and before=2019-12-01T23:59:59Z time period events using curl

Comment: I can't find anything in the Github API documentation that says there's a parameter to filter on a time period. I think you'll have to do the filtering on the returned data instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process the `JSON` data received from the `curl` request using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), a command-line `JSON` processor.

The one-liner command for getting repo events for a specific data range is as follows :

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo/events | jq '. [] | select (.created_at | fromdateiso8601 > 1572566400 and fromdateiso8601 < 1575244799)' | jq -s '.'
```

The dates `2019-11-01T00:00:00Z` and `2019-12-01T23:59:59Z` are in [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, so using built-in date handling functionality of [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Dates), ISO-8601 format can be represented in number of seconds since the Unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`). Checkout this snippet at [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/TswbXy3lDY) to convert the dates.

Date range is assumed to be this : `"2019-11-01T00:00:00Z" < date < "2019-12-01T23:59:59Z"`

[slurp mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29404575/10155936) (`-s`) in `jq` is used to convert the filtered `JSON` objects to `JSON`array.

[Reference for the filtering dates in jq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39882484/10155936)