# How can I use a JMESPath query to filter on strings ending with timestamp

Tags: aws-cli, jmespath

How can I use a JMESPath query to filter a property `Name` which starts with `abc`, and ends with a timestamp in the format `YYYYMMDD-HH`, for example: `abc-20230913-11`.

I know how to filter a string using `starts_with` and `ends_with`, but I am not sure how to filter a string that ends with a timestamp format `YYYYMMDD-HH`.

```bash
--query 'Clusters[?
           starts_with(Name, `abc`) == `true` 
           && ends_with(Name, ???)
         ].[Name]'
```

Comment: JSON does not understand dates, or at least [there is no date type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/what-is-the-right-json-date-format), so, in the same vain, JMESPath does not have any understanding of a date either. And since [there is no regex to accomplish this either](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.jep/issues/23), your requirement is not something achievable in JMESPath for the moment.

Comment: What you could do, though, for a workaround, is to parse your resulting JSON with a library like [tag:jq]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881728/jq-filter-json-by-dates